# What's the meaning of "and on back"

Tags: idiomatic-language

**Sentence:** *Yes, and your great-grandmother and great-grandfather, and on back.*

Comment: Welcome to ELL. It’s practice here to repeat one’s question in the body of the post. And to indicate what efforts one has expended to answer the question, along with the results of those efforts.

Comment: It should probably be "and so on, back."  I'm voting to close as you haven't provided the source of the quote.

Comment: The source is (american chapters: the two garcons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means “and other ancestors extending deeper into your family’s past.”